# How can I change modified date to the creation date stored in the meta data of a photo/video in mass?

Tags: video, backup, google, google-drive, photo

I am trying to download all of the photos and videos stored on my google photos account. When I download the files they are slapped with the download date as the modified date. However, I want to change all the modified dates over to the creation date stored in the metadata.

I know I can use the touch command in the command line to change this date. However, how can I do this in mass for every photo and video within a given folder?

Alternatively, is there an option to fix the issue at the source and ensure that when the videos and photos are downloaded their modified date is sourced from the media's metadata rather than the system date?

edit 8/1/22:
The marked answer effectively changes the dates for image files. However, it has no effects on video files. I have been looking at exiftool but cannot figure out what command to run to ensure every video's modified date is changed to the original date of creation contained in the metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `exiftool`, which you will first need to install:

```
sudo apt install  libimage-exiftool-perl
```

This command line tool has about 1 bazillion options for modifying image file data, but I believe that the command you want is

```
 exiftool '-FileModifyDate<DateTimeOriginal' DIR
```

where `DIR` is the directory name.  This is actually an example given in `man exiftool`

Comment: This works on the pictures. However, it does not change the modified date to the date the media was created for video files (mov and mp4).

Comment: @ExZerminator You may need to explore deeper into the man pages of exiftools - it does support read and write on mov and mp4 files, so I would first see if it is capable of reading the correct file date on those files for you.

Comment: @ExZerminator A little testing on my end:  `exiftool -ALL mymovie.MOV` lists the exif data for my files.  I executed   `exiftool -FileModifyDate+=4 *.MOV` and was able to change the file modify date, and `exiftool '-FileModifyDate<DateTimeOriginal' *.MOV` and was able to restore the date

Comment: Haha.  Actually `exiftool` has 2 bazillion options.